# Displaying menu on hovering over item in list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `ul` list on my web page navigation bar and is written somewhat as the following:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="index.htm" title="Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="project.htm" title="Project">Project</a></li>
<li><a href="sample.htm" title="Sample">Sample</a></li>
</ul>
```

On hovering the mouse over the `ul` list, the color of the items changes.

```
ul#nav li a:link,ul#nav li a:visited {color:#333333;text-decoration:none;}
ul#nav li a:hover,ul#nav li a:active {color:#a61607;text-decoration:none;}
```

However, I have a graphical menu to be displayed when the user hovers over `sample` a element. The menu is something like the following (one image of arrows and three hyperlinks):

```
               hyperlink 1
Arrow image /_ hyperlink 2
            \  hyperlink 3
```

How do I display this arrow image and the hyperlinks in the form of a menu, on hovering over the `sample` item in the `ul` list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle, which works as you need it to, I think.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ne227/1/