# Revealing text when hovering over a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the "OL" "Sublist" appear when I hover over the "FS1" list text in the drop down menu. Here is a demo of what i am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/EfLJJ/1/

Would it be possible for somebody to show me how I can make "OL" "Sublist" visible when I hover over the text in "UL" "List"?

The snippet of code i am looking at is:

CSS:

```
.wrap .sublist {text-decoration: none; list-style: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px;
                  visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0.8em; left: 3.8em; z-index: 600; font-weight: lighter; color: #222;}
        .wrap .sublist a {color: #06C; position: absolute; top: 3em; font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;}
        .fs1:hover .wrap {visibility: visible;}
```

HTML:

```
<ol class="sublist">
    <li>FS (All)</li>
    <li><a href="">FS</a></li>
</ol>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="fs1"><a href="">FS1</a></li>
    <li id="c1"><a href="">C1</a></li>
    <li id="wt1"><a href="">WT1</a></li>
    <li id="a1"><a href="">A1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587407/displaying-menu-on-hovering-over-item-in-list?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Javascript!
for example:

```
<script language="Javascript>
function appear() {
document.getElementById("sublist").style.display = "block";
}
function hide() {
document.getElementById("sublist").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<ol class="sublist" id="sublist">
...
</ol>
<ul class"list">
<li class="fs1" onmouseover="appear()" onmouseout="hide()"><a href="">FS1</li>
...
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes that is probably going to be the best option. I have put the code together in JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EfLJJ/8/ . But it doesn't work? Could you send me a working demo?

Comment: Sorry, i made some dizzy code ;-) I updated your Fiddle just now http://jsfiddle.net/EfLJJ/11/ and I'm wondering about why on JS Fiddle it don't works like it should, but on my localhost it runs perfect...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
<style>
.sublist {text-decoration: none; list-style: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px;
                  display:none; position: absolute; top: 0.8em; left: 3.8em; z-index: 600; font-weight: lighter; color: #222;}
        .wrap .sublist a {color: #06C; position: absolute; top: 3em; font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;}
        .fs1:hover .wrap {visibility: visible;}
.su
</style>
<script>
function show()
{
document.getElementById("sublist").style.display="block";
}
</script>
<ol class="sublist" id="sublist">
    <li>FS (All)</li>
    <li><a href="">FS</a></li>
</ol>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="fs1"><a href="" onmouseover="show();">FS1</a></li>
    <li id="c1"><a href="">C1</a></li>
    <li id="wt1"><a href="">WT1</a></li>
    <li id="a1"><a href="">A1</a></li></div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach eventhandlers for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to `.fs1` that toggle the `.sublist`.  It is also important to use `display:none` to hide the `.sublist` initially.

**Javascript**

```
$(".list .fs1").bind({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $(".sublist").show();
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(".sublist").hide();
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap .sublist {
    text-decoration: none; 
    list-style: none; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 20px;
    display:none; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.8em; 
    left: 3.8em; 
    z-index: 600; 
    font-weight: lighter; 
    color: #222;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/EfLJJ/2/

Comment: Thanks for the update this works in jsfiddle but it doesnt work in Dreamweaver?